How to parse actively fetched stack information of '[NSThread callStackSymbols]'？
I use '[NSThread callStackSymbols]' method to record app stack information and write to log file. In debug environment, it works fine. But in release environment(app submitted by App Store), '[NSThread callStackSymbols]' can only record stack symbol address which not parsed.
I want to write a script or tool to parse these stack symbol addresses. The solution I am going to try is to convert it into a .crash file. I would like to ask if anyone has any other good methods.
Thanks!
  - 8 : "8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001cdf557ac 137A95AA-DA6D-332C-BC01-E13BB9B6E317 + 17545132"
  - 9 : "9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001cdf5513c 137A95AA-DA6D-332C-BC01-E13BB9B6E317 + 17543484"
  - 10 : "10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001cdf55a2c 137A95AA-DA6D-332C-BC01-E13BB9B6E317 + 17545772"
  - 11 : "11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001cd1c2950 137A95AA-DA6D-332C-BC01-E13BB9B6E317 + 3311952"
  - 12 : "12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001cd0d5b4c 137A95AA-DA6D-332C-BC01-E13BB9B6E317 + 2341708"
  - 13 : "13  UIKitCore                           0x00000001ccfff23c 137A95AA-DA6D-332C-BC01-E13BB9B6E317 + 1462844"
  - 14 : "14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001ccfff960 137A95AA-DA6D-332C-BC01-E13BB9B6E317 + 1464672"
  - 15 : "15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001ccfffb10 137A95AA-DA6D-332C-BC01-E13BB9B6E317 + 1465104"
  - 16 : "16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001caa5d0c4 6B22DD81-3585-3BE6-BC77-BA19810EC0F2 + 266436"
  - 17 : "17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001caa2c080 6B22DD81-3585-3BE6-BC77-BA19810EC0F2 + 65664"
  - 18 : "18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001caa2713c 6B22DD81-3585-3BE6-BC77-BA19810EC0F2 + 45372"

